# Not able to use One Drive API for One Drive for Business of users belonging to other organizations

Tags: azure, office365, onedrive, office365api

we have a web app that allows access to users one drive by doing oauth https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/.... I was able to get access to the drive apis for one drive personal and get access to the documents of that account.

When i followed the steps for integration for one drive for business I found that i can access one drive for business only if my app is registered with Azure of the user trying to login.
But we want any users from any organisation to come to our webapp and access their OO for Business documents from our app. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an app on Azure you need to enable multitenant feature.

You can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/add-common-consent-manually) info how to make app multitenant.

Thanks